# Maven Test: Checkout some other repository for some test classes During Jenkin Build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Consider having 3 repository repo1[Microservice1], repo2[Microservice2], repo3[GeneralRepo Include configuration]

repo1,repo2 having the test classes. These test classes are uses repo3 for sharing common details.

Running maven test works fine locally. Need to implement the same in Jenkins build Environment to pass the test cases.

One way I can do in the Jenkins pipeline adding new stage to checkout another repo3.

Is any maven configuration to checkout the repo3 with the scope of the test. Which can be used by mvn test.

Comment: Actually, I would think whether this construction is really fortunate.

Comment: Violating share nothing principle in microservices...which results in such strange setups...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would build and deploy the code from your repo3 as a separate library and include that as a dependency in your other repos.

If not, you might consider doing so.

If you can't, then you might do what you said yourself: have the Jenkins pipeline checkout your repo3.